No. Of times of derivative taken to form differential equation.
To form a differential equation we take $n$ no. of derivatives where $n$=the no. of arbitary constants present in the equation.
For Example, lets take $A\cos(x)+B\sin(x)=y$.

To form a differential equation we take derivatives $2$ times as no.of arbitary constants here are $2$($A$ and $B$).
$$\Rightarrow \frac{d}{dx}\left(A\cos(x)\right)+\frac{d}{dx}\left(B\sin(x)\right)=\frac{dy}{dx} \implies y'=-A\sin(x)+B\cos(x)$$.
Now again taking another derivative for $y'$ we get $y''=-A\cos(x)-B\sin(x)$.
We can write this as $y''=-(A\cos(x)+B\sin(x))\implies y''=-y$.
Therefore the differential equation formed here is $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+y=0$.
But still if we take derivative $1$ more time for the equation $y''=-A\cos(x)-B\sin(x)$, we get 
$y'''=A\sin(x)-B\cos(x)$.
We can write this as $y'''=-(-A\sin(x)+B\cos(x)\implies y'''=-y'$.
Therefore the differential equation formed here is $\frac{d^3y}{dx^3}+\frac{dy}{dx}=0$.
But the correct differential equation is $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+y=0$.
I can't understand why the differential equation cannot be $\frac{d^3y}{dx^3}+\frac{dy}{dx}=0$.
But still taking an extra derivative does not mess anything up in this example. But my maths sir told that there are some cases where we should not take derivatives more than the no. of arbitary constants.
Please help me understand this. And also give me the cases where taking an extra derivative messes everything up.

The general solution to $y'''=-y'$ is $y=A\cos x + B\sin x + C$. The third derivative adds a new term to the general solution.

You seem to be saying, if you know a function, what is the smallest differential degree for which the function is a solution. But you seem to want a specific type of differential equation, because $y=A\sin x+B\cos X$ is a solution to $y'+y=A\sin x+B\cos x +A\cos x-B\sin x.$ So maybe you could clarify your questiion.

How do you integrate twice $y''+y=0$ if you don't know $y?$ I mean, if you know $y,$ you can find $y,$ of course, but how do you integrate this twice without knowing $y?$

@Gonçalo Thats what i thought too but my sir told there are cases where taking another extra derivative makes the equation wrong

@ThomasAndrews yeah we knkw y=Acosx+Bsinx we arejust verifying whether we get the initiwl equation or not by taking derivatives 2 times

You said integrating two times. "If we integrate this differential equation two times..." No idea what that means.q

I integrate the solution 2 times to show you guys that that integrating the y'' equation 2 times and integrating the other y''' equation 3 times we get the initial equation

"But still taking an extra derivative does not mess anything up in this example" It does. Any constant function $y(x) = c$ satisfies $y''' + y'=0$ (because $y''' = y' = 0$). But no non-zero constant function satisfies $y'' + y = 0$. In fact, whenever you differentiate more than necessary, you will end up creating more solutions (more than what you expect : in this case, you only expected $A \cos x + B \sin x$, but if you look at $y''' +y' =0$ you also have the constant solutions, which are not included in the family $A \cos x + B \sin x$.)

"And also give me the cases where taking an extra derivative messes everything up" I'm not able to come up with a case where taking an extra derivative doesn't mess things up. I'm also not able to come up with a proof that extra derivatives always mess things up, but I'll leave that to someone else.

@SarveshRavichandranIyer I was away for some time...Thanks for the idea i got it now
